# How to use the result of an iteration to re-iterate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I need to create a new array from another with the condition:
for example from an array

```
mainArr: [
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"root"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "parentId":1,
            "name":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":148,
            "parentId":2,
            "name":"3"
        },
        {
            "id":151,
            "parentId":148,
            "name":"4"
        },
        {
            "id":152,
            "parentId":151,
            "name":"5"
        }
    ]
```

I need to make an array `['1','2','148','151']` which means the path from "parentId"'s to "id":152 - (argument for this function).

I think main logic can be like this:

```
const parentsArr = [];
mainArr.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === id) {
        parentsArr.unshift(`${item.parentId}`);
    }
```

and the result `{item.parentId}` should be used to iterate again. But I don't understand how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function for this. First you can transform your array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where each id from each object points to its object. Doing this allows you to `.get()` the object with a given id efficiently. For each object, you can get the parentId, and if it is defined, rerun your `traverse()` object again searching for the parent id. When you can no longer find a parentid, then you're at the root, meaning you can return an empty array to signify no parentid object exist:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"root"},{"id":2,"parentId":1,"name":"2"},{"id":148,"parentId":2,"name":"3"},{"id":151,"parentId":148,"name":"4"},{"id":152,"parentId":151,"name":"5"}];

const transform = arr => new Map(arr.map((o) => [o.id, o]));

const traverse = (map, id) => {
  const startObj = map.get(+id);
  if("parentId" in startObj)
    return [...traverse(map, startObj.parentId), startObj.parentId]; 
  else
    return [];
}

console.log(traverse(transform(arr), "152"));
```

If you want to include "152" in the result, you can change your recursive function to use the `id` argument, and change the base-case to return `[id]` (note that the `+` in front of id is used to convert it to a number if it is a string):

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"root"},{"id":2,"parentId":1,"name":"2"},{"id":148,"parentId":2,"name":"3"},{"id":151,"parentId":148,"name":"4"},{"id":152,"parentId":151,"name":"5"}];

const transform = arr => new Map(arr.map((o) => [o.id, o]));

const traverse = (map, id) => {
  const startObj = map.get(+id);
  if("parentId" in startObj)
    return [...traverse(map, startObj.parentId), +id]; 
  else
    return [+id];
}

console.log(traverse(transform(arr), "152"));
```

Comment: Thanks for solution! How else I can put id ('152' - in this case) to result array?

Comment: @EugeneK - no worries

Comment: How else I can put id ('152' - in this case) to result array?

Comment: @EugeneK see the second code snippet (you'll need to expand it)

Comment: Thnx. And one more thing) How to check on "undefined". if "id" doesn't exist or "1" in the array, I get error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'parentId' in undefined"

Comment: Or, how check better on - map.includes(id), if not - return ['1']

Comment: @EugeneK. you can add a check to see if `startObj` is `undefined`, and if it is, an empty array before you check the key

Answer (score 1):

I would start by indexing the data by id using `reduce`

```
var byId = data.reduce( (acc,i) => {
  acc[i.id] = i
  return acc;
},{});
```

And then just go through using a loop and pushing the id to a result array

```
var item = byId[input];
var result = []
while(item.parentId) {
  result.push(item.parentId)
  item = byId[item.parentId];
}
```

Live example:

```js
const input = 152;
const data = [ { "id":1, "name":"root" }, { "id":2, "parentId":1, "name":"2" }, { "id":148, "parentId":2, "name":"3" }, { "id":151, "parentId":148, "name":"4" }, { "id":152, "parentId":151, "name":"5" } ]

var byId = data.reduce( (acc,i) => {
  acc[i.id] = i
  return acc;
},{});

var item = byId[input];
var result = []
while(item.parentId) {
  result.push(item.parentId)
  item = byId[item.parentId];
}
console.log(result.reverse());
```

Comment: @NickParsons ha, yeah of course. How stupid of me.

Comment: Haha, dw, I like this answer since it's simple compared to my recursive approach

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
parentsArr.unshift(`${item.parentId}`);
```

To this

```
parentsArr.push(`${item.parentId}`);
```

Then try

```
console.log(parentsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. Basically a mix of Janek and Nicks answers. It's just 2 steps:

1. transform code to a map.
2. extract the ancester_id's with a little function

```js
let data = [
    {"id":1,"name":"root"},
    {"id":2,"parentId":1,"name":"2"},
    {"id":148,"parentId":2,"name":"3"},
    {"id":151,"parentId":148,"name":"4"},
    {"id":152,"parentId":151,"name":"5"}
];
    
data = data.reduce( (acc, value) => {
  // could optionally filter out the id here
  return acc.set(value.id, value)
}, new Map());


function extract_ancestors( data, id ) {
  let result = [];
  while( data.get( id ).parentId ) {
    id = data.get( id ).parentId;
    result.push(id)
  }
  return result;
}

// some visual tests
console.log( extract_ancestors( data, 152 )  );
console.log( extract_ancestors( data, 148 )  );
console.log( extract_ancestors( data, 1 )  );
```

PS: My OOP tendencies start to itch so much from this haha.